# Why function in a loop is working only once?

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, google-apps-script, progress-bar

I'm working on a progressbar with Google App Script and JQuery. 
When I click on submit, the following code run:

```
    var i=0;
    while (i<100){
      var prog=google.script.run.countTime();
      i+=prog;
      button.progressIncrement(i);
    }
```

The progressbar is only feeded at 10% and the execution is stopped.

The countTime() function is not very important (only returns 10 for the moment):

```
function countTime(){
   return 10;
}
```

But if I remove the function, it works (100%):

```
 while (i<100){
    var prog=10;
    i+=prog;
    button.progressIncrement(i);
 }
```

If I remove my loop and write something like this:

```
    var i=0;
    var prog=google.script.run.countTime();
    i+=prog;
    button.progressIncrement(i);
    var prog=google.script.run.countTime();
    i+=prog;
    button.progressIncrement(i);
    var prog=google.script.run.countTime();
    i+=prog;
    button.progressIncrement(i);
    var prog=google.script.run.countTime();
    i+=prog;
    button.progressIncrement(i);
    var prog=google.script.run.countTime();
    i+=prog;
    button.progressIncrement(i);
    (....)
```

The progressbar works to 100% too.

What is wrong with the function inside the while?

Comment: Have you tried to debug it? By the way, everything above is arhitecturally wrong.

Comment: I can't debug the html file and the only function from Google Script here is countTime(). What is arhitecturally wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[google.script.run()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run) doesn't return a value, it runs asynchronously. You pass it a callback function to get a value back from it via [withSuccessHandler()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run#withSuccessHandler(Function)). For example in your client side code:

```
function onSuccess(valueFromServer) {

    // do something with valueFromServer
}

google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(onSuccess).doSomethingServerSide()
```

And server side:

```
function doSomethingServerSide() {
    return valueFromServer
}
```

Comment: besides, there are quotas as to how many simultaneous calls you can make to the server.