# Google Script - How to add a function in value="" in HTML with a JS function?

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script

So it's my first post ever on StackOverflow, so sorry if I tell something weird:

So, I would like to display the date from the function Today() in my input with the id "file_name" (so, it will be like a default value):

**webAppBoot.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <?!= include('WebAppBoot-css'); ?>
</head>

<body>
    <form>
        <div class="input-field col s6">
          <input id="file_name" type="text" class="validate">
          <label for="file_name">File name</label>
        </div>
    </form>
<?!= include('WebAppBoot-js'); ?>
</body>

</html>
```

**index.gs**

```
function doGet(request) {
  return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('WebAppBoot')
      .evaluate();
}

function include(filename) {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile(filename)
      .getContent();
}
```

I know that I can totally write the function Today() from this file
**WebAppBoot-js.html**

```
<script>
    document.getElementById("file_name").value = google.script.run.Today();    
</script>
```

But I prefer to add it from this file :
**functions.gs**

```
  function Today() {
  var today = new Date();
  var dd = String(today.getDate()).padStart(2, '0');
  var mm = String(today.getMonth() + 1).padStart(2, '0')
  var yyyy = today.getFullYear();
  return mm + '/' + dd + '/' + yyyy;
}
```

So, as I tried, it's not working as you can see:
[undefined value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oe0nQ.png)

But I can still see that the function is working with a `Logger.log(Today())` function
So, to resume, in definitive, I would like to have that when we open the form:[Final result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jzpMc.png)

Can you help me ? Thank you

Comment: I don't know why this was closed but you need to look at withSuccessHandler for google.script.run  https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run#withFailureHandler(Function)

Comment: @Tanaike, please reopen this question.  Your link does not resolve his issue.

Comment: @TheWizEd When I saw OP's question, I thought that `document.getElementById("file_name").value = google.script.run.Today();` is the modification point. So, I had tried to prepare the answer for this. But, before I post it, when I searched the duplicated question, I found https://stackoverflow.com/q/32862775 . So I flagged this as the duplicated question. If I misunderstood OP's question, I apologize.

Comment: @Tanaike, he needs to include withSuccessHandler in his call to Today() to get the return value.

Comment: @TheWizEd Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. About `he needs to include withSuccessHandler in his call to Today() to get the return value.`, it's yes. So I flagged this question as the duplicated question of https://stackoverflow.com/q/32862775 If I misunderstood OP's issue, I apologize.

Comment: @Tanaike, sorry I looked at https://stackoverflow.com/q/32862775 question but not the answer below.  So yes that does show the need for withSuccessHandler.

Comment: @TheWizEd Don't worry. I believe that your comment is important and it indicates your serious stance on questions. Also, I have cases where I couldn't find the duplicated questions. Or, even when I found the duplicated question, if I thought that OP's script is required to be modified largely, there is the case I proposed an answer. So, please keep your stance. If my English in this comment is not correct, I apologize.

Comment: @Tanaike, your english is perfect.

Comment: Hello, I'm really sorry for the duplicate, I'm quite new in tech, but I still can't really figure out how it's working. I'm not really good

I tried many things, for example, I tried that:

`function onSuccess() {
     Time()
}

    document.getElementById("file_name").value = google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(onSuccess)`

But it's still not working :(

Comment: It's still not working. Thank you. :)